# display a grid <p> row vs a grid <div> row

Tags: css

And why is a grid row `<p>` different then a grid row `<div>` ???

Sorry if it's something obvious but it just doesn't make any sense to me XD

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 20px;
  grid-auto-columns: auto;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
}

.box {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="box">test</p>
  <div class="box">test</div>
  <div class="box">test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `height` of the `p` element is 0.  I'm not exactly sure why but the `grid-auto-rows` rule for the grid `container` is causing it.  Without it, the `p` balloons to 50px hight, including padding.

This padding is something the browser set.  I like to use a `css reset`. They are simple CSS rules that undo the common problems these default styles cause.  There are SEVERAL of these and people prefer different resets for different reasons.  [I rather like this one](https://github.com/jgthms/minireset.css/blob/master/minireset.css)

EDIT: fixed code snippet.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 20px;
  grid-auto-columns: auto;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
}

.box {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="box">test</p>
  <div class="box">test</div>
  <div class="box">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm ok thx but i put the word `test` in it how can it be `0` it's so inconsistent ?

Comment: it should be atleast `20px` to make any sense regarding the padding or margin reset

Comment: Excuse me, I looked at the Computed styles in the developer window and it reported `height 0px`.  I see now that 2px are showing.  It's because there is 18px of padding on that `p` pushing it down into it's sibling.

Comment: adding `margin: 0; padding: 0;` in the box class fixed it. Can you add the modified snipped to your answer please so other can see the result :)

Answer (score 2):

The largest difference between using `<p>` and `<div>` USED TO BE that you cannot nest additional elements inside `<p>` the way you can using `<div>`. However, the `<p>` tag seems to have become more forgiving in HTML5, making this allowable - any phrasing elements (including images and other `<p>` tags) work fine. The main reason to pick one over the other in MODERN DAY is 1) It marks a semantic difference, making the code more readable by others, and 2) `<p>` by default adds a margin above and below the paragraph, while `<div>` adds no additional margin.

Comment: This being said, it is still considered bad form to include block elements inside a `<p>` tag.

Comment: but I didn't include a block element in a `<p>` element in this case right?

Comment: Correct, you did not. I was simply quoting the "unofficial rules" of HTML, which state that though `<p>` is a block element itself, it is not advisable to place other block elements inside it.